# Rails - Nested Attributes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm using nested attributes to user adresses.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, update_only: :true
```

I'm passing the address id as hidden field at sign-in.

```
<%= form_for (@user), :html => {:class => 'lead-form'} do |f| %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control', placeholder: "Email", required: true %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, class:'form-control', placeholder: "Senha", required: true %>
                    <%= f.fields_for :address do |addresses_form| %>
                    <%= addresses_form.hidden_field :address_id, :value => @address.id %>
                    <% end %>
                <%= f.submit 'Pedir meu convite', class: "button lead-form-button" %>
            <% end %>
```

The e-mail is validate as uniqueness. So, when somebody try to sign in with an already taken e-mail the address params are passed as nil and i get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#create
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea how can i fix that?

Here is my controller:

```
  def new
@user = User.new
@address = @user.build_address
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params) 
if @user.save 
 log_in @user
 flash[:success] = "Você está dentro. Esse é seu perfil! =) "
 redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
end
end

 private
 def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:id, :primeiro_nome, :sobrenome, :email, :cpf,     :telefone, :sexo, :data_de_nascimento, :password, address_attributes: [:id, :logradouro, :bairro, :cidade, :uf, :complemento, :cep])
 end
```

ps: The association is one to one. How can i call the address attributes if i don't pass as hidden.

Comment: But if i don't force to create an user address with nil values to user, how can i call it at the update page? The association is one to one.

Comment: So, you need to have a nested form.

Comment: Watch this, it is an older version of rails but the idea is the same. After looking at your code for a while, you will probably need to start over. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1.

Comment: But i have a nested form. Look at the fields_for at the form above.

It works with inputs without problems with validation because the form pass the address id. But when somebody try to input a value already taken the address ID is passed as nil.

Answer (score 0):

Address belongs to user? If yes, you just call @user.address

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using `try` method:

```
<%= addresses_form.hidden_field :address_id, :value => @address.try(:id) %>
```